# Mongo DB Sorting by mutual friends

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following collections

Users

```
User = {
  name: string,
  facebook_friends: [{
    name: String,
    fb_id: String
  }]
}
```

Listings

```
Listing = {
 title: string,
 owner_friends_ids: [String]
}
```

I would like to show a list of all listings by the number of mutual friends. Is it possible to also include the names of mutual friends through the same query or will I need to use one query to sort and then another to get the names of mutual friends?

Comment: Can you clarify what input you have?  Mutual friends of ... two fb_ids? user_ids?

Comment: where is mutual friends detail?